# Negative homogenization on the positive orthant

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry

I am trying to find a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ that is strictly positive on the positive orthant but its homogenization is not (except at 0).
I d especially like to know if there is an example in 1 variable.

The question is probably not that hard but I dont really have an idea how to construct one.